# Bird's eye view of the entire Image

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to find the Bird's Eye View of the Image. I am using OpenCV to do so. The image and the code are below. I have seen some implementations which actually find the BEV of the part of the image and not the complete image. However, I would like to get the BEV of the complete image. The size of the image is `width, height = 1536, 512`

[This](https://nikolasent.github.io/opencv/2017/05/07/Bird%27s-Eye-View-Transformation.html) link is what I have used to understand the operations. However, this uses a cropped area of the image for the projected BEV.

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
IMAGE_H = 512
IMAGE_W = 1536
src = np.float32([[0, IMAGE_H], [1207, IMAGE_H], [0, 0], [IMAGE_W, 0]])
dst = np.float32([[10, IMAGE_H], [1500, IMAGE_H], [0, 0], [IMAGE_W, 0]])
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst) # The transformation matrix
Minv = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(dst, src) # Inverse transformation
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg') # Read the test img
warped_img = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (IMAGE_W, IMAGE_H)) # Image warping
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(warped_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)) # Show results
plt.show()
```

However, I don't get the desired result. I suspect there is something wrong with `src` and `dst` values. How do I adjust these values to get the BEV of the complete image?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

That's basically a matter of parameter tweaking. You can start off with the following:

```
OUT_H_FACTOR = 8
src = np.float32([[0, IMAGE_H], [IMAGE_W, IMAGE_H], [848, 189], [927, 189]])
dst = np.float32([[500, IMAGE_H * OUT_H_FACTOR], [IMAGE_W - 500, IMAGE_H * OUT_H_FACTOR], [500, 0], [IMAGE_W - 500, 0]])
```

No matter how good the parameters are, there will be lots of distortion involved. Without the `OUT_H_FACTOR`:
[image]

and with its effect: [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to reduce the distortion?

Comment: As we are squeezing the last bit of information from the pixels further away from the center of the image, this might be a very tricky task. This might also require knowledge about the optics being used. You might try to play around with the few parameters in order to get the line at x=1200 a little bit more straight but that's it, I'm afraid.

Comment: Oh no. Unfortunately, I don't have any information regarding the optics. I will play with the src and dst values a bit I guess and see where it takes me

Comment: With the homography based tansform we cant get around distortions introduced for vertical objects.